# Is there a need to protect users if they reveal traceable personal information?

Tags: discussion, privacy

A user was asking a sensitive question. There were comments saying "change your username and picture". I went and traced his picture and name and arrived at a website with their resume (no address thankfully, but I have a city), Twitter, e-mail, GitHub, and some other social media information.

What is the next step here? Just let the user update it at their own pace? Can moderators step in and censor something?

Answer (score 4):

That's up to the user.

There's nothing *requiring* that a user be anonymous; in fact, many people use their real names and photos because SO is well-known enough that having rep here can help you get a job.

So if the user wants to be associated with whatever it is, then that's their decision. If they *don't*, then there are a couple options.

If there's sensitive information in a post, the first step is to edit it out. Then flag for moderator attention - they'll be able to redact the information from the revision history.

If they just don't want the entire post attached to their name, then they can request to be disassociated from the post - the post will not show them as the author. You can do this by either using "contact us" or a moderator flag.

And, of course, you can always edit your own username and avatar if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If the user is concerned about it you should flag for moderator attention. Only moderators can edit sensitive information out of the edit history. In the mean time, the user should try to remove as much as they can, so a few pointers in that direction would be helpful.